# Logic of ternary operator in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, encryption, aes

I'm studying some AES implementation C code. The encryption code needs to get the password passed as argument, and so the encrypted and the output file.

I understand it *reads* the password and that also treats it and turns it into a key. But there's this cycle where I can't really understand what it's doing.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 unsigned long rk[RKLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
 unsigned char key[KEYLENGTH(KEYBITS)];
 int i;
 int nrounds;
 char *password;
 FILE *output;
 if (argc < 3) {
  fputs("Missing argument\n", stderr);
  return 1;
 }                                              
 password = argv[1]
 for (i = 0; i < sizeof(key); i++)
  key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;  /* HERE IS WHERE I CAN'T GET IT */
```

What's exactly happening with the key string? I think there's some logical stuff and bits operations.

Comment: You need to learn pointers.

Comment: Looks like the question also might be about the use of the ternary operator (the ?).  It's just a shorter way of writing an if-else statement.

Comment: This may be slightly off-topic, but a proper [key-derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) would be an improvement on just plugging the password bytes into the key.

Comment: Thanks for comment @JeffreyHantin, I only can say I know the BASICS of encryption.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin in this case, more specifically a password based key derivation function such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), `bcrypt` or `scrypt`.

Comment: @owlstead bcrypt and scrypt cannot be used for password derivation, but PBKDF2 is a good choice.

Comment: @owlstead is **FAMOUS** in here!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The loop you are looking at is copying `sizeof(key)` bytes from the `password` string into the `key` buffer, and padding the rest of the buffer with `0` if the length of the `password` string is smaller than `sizeof(key)`.

The ternary operator has the form:

> *condition* **`?`** *expression-1* **`:`** *expression-2*

If *condition* is true, then *expression-1* is evaluated, otherwise *expression-2* is evaluated. There is short circuiting, in that only one of the expressions is ever evaluated. So, in your code:

```
    key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;
```

Once `*password != 0` becomes false, `password` does not get incremented again.

Answer (score 6):

For each byte in the key, if there's a corresponding byte in the password (originally `argv[1]`), copy that byte to the key; else copy a 0 (byte) to the key.  It's a long-winded way of writing:

```
strncpy(key, password, sizeof(key));
```

(It is also one of the few times I'll ever recommend using `strncpy()`; in general, it doesn't do what people expect, but here, it does exactly what is required.)

Comment: It's not precisely identical to `strncpy`; the ternary operator loop also zero-fills the remainder of `key` if `password` is shorter than `sizeof(key) - 1`.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin: `strncpy()` does that too, which is why I +1'd Jonathan's answer.

Comment: @jxh: well I'll be darned, I thought it stopped at the first null.  I guess that just proves the point about how `strncpy` in general doesn't do what people expect. :)

Comment: And just for good measure, [a rant on the topic of `strncpy()`](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html) by Keith Thompson.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly :

```
 key[i] = *password != 0 ? *password++ : 0;  /* HERE IS WHERE I CAN'T GET IT */

 =

 if (*password != 0) { key[i]=*password++; } else { key[i]=0; } ;
```